# Should progressive web app use simple_token_authentication or jwt token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, jwt

I have two different server mobile app server and rails server. I am using devise - session management for web application and simple_token_authentication gem for mobile app as it is using JSON API to communicate to rails server.

So what are disadvantages of simple_token_authentication gem, as JWT is being used widely? or what are security concern if i use simple_token_authentication gem over JWT

Comment: You should use https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper because it's a standard Oauth 2 provider for rails.

Comment: You can use JWT library for generating access_token

Comment: Yes, I know JWT library and how to use it, but my project already have simple_token_authentication gem, then why should i change it to jwt? What are the problems with simple_token_authentication gem?